# Filter Column and enter Range as Input Box

Tags: excel, vba

Everybody,

I want to show only those columns in a table whose headers I enter in an input field.

I also want to use an InputBox to select the area to which the filter should be applied (e.g. row 4).

For this I would like to have only a part of the colums header to be sufficient to filter the columns.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

If a column carries the heading: eQuantum (02) then I would like to enter only a part of the heading, no matter in which length (e.g. eQuan), and then all columns should be shown which carry this partial heading. All other columns should be hidden.

The script is not running yet.

But here the code is as far as I got.

```
Sub Spalten_Filtern_Horizontal_InputBox()
Dim Zelle As Range
Dim Bereich As Range
Dim FilterText As String
Dim Einblenden As Range

Set Bereich = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter Row", Type:=8)
  If Bereich Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
  Else
    Bereich.Select
      End If
FilterText = InputBox("Enter Header")
For Each Zelle In Bereich
    If Zelle.Text Like FilterText Then
        If Einblenden Is Nothing Then
            Set Einblenden = Zelle
        Else
            Set Einblenden = Union(Einblenden, Zelle)
        End If
    End If
Next
Bereich.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Einblenden.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post some sample data.

Comment: Do you have an actual `ListObject`?

Comment: Prefer `.Value` to `.Text` - `If Zelle.Value`. Then I'm assuming you need wildcards for the `Like`: `If Zelle.Value Like "*" & FilterText & "*" Then`.

Comment: I edited the Code above. 
Maybe it is a bit clearer now. I'd would be great to enter the partial Header text and the row. 
For Example: Rows(7).Select. 
And the 7 should be entered with the input box. Maybe something like that:  
    FilterText = InputBox("Enter Header"). Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select row(s) to remove",type:=8)
    If not rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = rng.EntireRow. 
    rng.Select. 
Thank you for you Help ans patience